# Изменить лист из активити во фрагменте

Tags: activity, android, java, android-fragment

Хочу из активити во фрагменте изменить лист. 
Выкидывает ошибку строки:

```
Fragment frag1 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label,  list1);
ListView lIstView  = (ListView) frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Последняя строка выводит ошибку:

> 12-18 11:00:01.066
> 9961-9961/com.example.eldos.callreport
> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main Process:
> com.example.eldos.callreport, PID:
> 9961 java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Could not execute method of the
> activity at
> android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
> at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
> at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
> at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
> at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
> at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
> at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method) Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> at
> android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
>             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method) Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> com.example.eldos.callreport.MainActivity.call(MainActivity.java:122)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
>             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)

Comment: В какой момент вызывается эта строка (на которой возникает ошибка)? Может быть, у фрагмента метод onCreateView() еще не успевает вызваться, и, как следствие, getView() == null??

Comment: Как выше уже написали, случайно frag1 у Вас не null часом ? Давайте полный (относительно ) код, потому что так Вам никто точно не скажет что и как.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы выбрали не самый удачный подход к решению проблемы.

Связь меж активити и фрагменами сложна, неоднозначна и ведёт к множеству проблем при неправильном понимании жизненного цикла обоих элементов.

Лучше всего (согласно моему опыту) не общаться с фрагментом напрямую из активити, а использовать, например, [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

**Задача:**

Обновить список из активити, присвоив ему адаптер с данными, кои есть в активити. Для этого:

**Решение:**

1) В onCreateView() фрагмента находим ListView и присваиваем его переменной фрагмента

```
ListView lV;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //inflate root view
    View v;
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURS_FRAGMENT_LAYOUT_WITH_LIST_VIEW, container, false);
        this.lV=v.findViewById(R.id.YOURS_LIST_VIEW_IN_FRAGMENTS_LAYOUT_ID);
        return v;
    }
```

2) Создаём во фрагменте метод, принимающий данные для списка, инициализирующий адаптер и назначающий его списку:

```
private void setAdapterForListView(String[] yoursStringArrayWithData)
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label,  yoursStringArrayWithData);
    this.lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

3) Описываем как должен фрагмент реагировать на сообщения LocalBroadcastManager:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
                //наши данные из активити придут внутри Intent
                //значит надо их вытащить
                String[] yoursStringArrayWithDataFromIntent = intent.getStringArrayExtra("stringKeyToExtractData");
                //вызываем наш метод, коий сделает адаптер с пришедшими данными
                //и присвоит его списку
        setAdapterForListView(yoursStringArrayWithDataFromIntent )
    }
};
```

4) Фрагмент должен знать, что умеет принимать сообщения и реагировать на них.
Пишем эту строку в onCreate() фрагмента.

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.act).registerReceiver(receiver,
    new IntentFilter("setAdapterToListView"));
```

5) Важно научить фрагмент отмене регистрации на приём сообщений и очистке памяти. Пишем:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    //если reciver существует, то отменяем регистрацию и стираем его.
    if (receiver != null)
    {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(act).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        receiver = null;
    }
    // Не забываем вызвать super метод в конце
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

6) Осталось только из активити послать сообщение с данными для адаптера, которое будет принято и обработано фрагментом. Пишем в нужном месте активити:

```
//Наши данные для адаптера
String[] data={"раз", "два", "три", "рубль", "расти"};
//Создаём интент, пихаем в него наши данные
Intent intent=new Intent("setAdapterToListView");
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("stringKeyToExtractData", data);
intent.putExtras(b);
//Посылаем сообщение с данными
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Итого:**

1) В нужный момент (по клику или по приходу данных) из активити посылаем сообщение с данными.

2) Фрагмент ловит сообщение (определяет что это ему сообщение по строке, коя передана в конструктор intent.

3) Делает всё что нужно. В данном случае - вытаскивает данные, передаёт их списку.

**Возможные проблемы:**

Надо помнить о жизненном цикле. Отсылать сообщение с данными из onCreate() активити нет смысла, т.к. фрагментов ещё нет, разметки в них нет, приложение падает.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я запускаю его и он вроде бы не доходит до фрагмента, в дебаггере написано так.

    intent = {android.content.Intent@831700928368}"Intent { act=setAdapterToListView }"
    b = {android.os.Bundle@831700929696}"Bundle[{stringKeyToExtractData=[Ljava.lang.String;@529e6ca8}]"
    mParcelledData = Cannot find local variable 'mParcelledData'
    mClassLoader = Cannot find local variable 'mClassLoader'
    mMap = Cannot find local variable 'mMap'

Может быть это не проблема. У меня сейчас так

    в активити я наследуюсь от FragmentActivity
    а в фрагменте я наследуюсь от Fragment

Comment: 
и если я использую Oncreate активити выдает ошибку в         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
поэтому я сделал инициализацию в onCreateView,

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("setAdaperToListView"));
а так вот работает 
но до него не доходит вещение, как я понял в чем может быть проблема, 
я поставил дебагеры в фрагменте в местах принятия вещания и методах но они не сработали видимо не дошло

Comment: то есть имею ввиду что если oncreate во фрагменте будет то почему то выдает ошибку, по этому мне приходится использовать onCreateView

Comment: @eldqs, а в каком месте сообщение отправляете? По клику по кнопке?
И я не знаю, как дебагер работает... Я пользую логи: 

>Log.d("myLog", "myMessage");

И им проверяю, куда код зашёл, куда нет, значения переменных etc.